# combo box data binding issue in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, combobox

I'm loading  5 combo boxes on my page and i loaded my 4 combo boxes withour any issue but the 5th one is giving me a hell..

i'll post the code which i have done here...pls correct me if i'm wrong..

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="605,131,0,0"
  Name="Cboadproducts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168"    TabIndex="3" 
  DisplayMemberPath="AdProduct" SelectedValuePath="AdProdctID" />
```

Code:-

```
   Cboadproducts.ItemsSource = null;
   List<MyRef.Country> list = ee.Result.ToList();
   list.Insert(0, new MyRef.Country() { AdProduct = "Select", AdProdctID = -1 });
   Cboadproducts.ItemsSource = list;
```

I'm gettin the value from DB but I dunno what causing this trouble..
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Magz

Comment: "giving me a hell" is not really a good enough description of your problem.  What actually happens?  Have you single stepped the code and examined the variables to determine they contain what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set  `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in the xaml

and

set `Cboadproducts.DataContext = list;` in code

**EDIT**

Code:

```
public class Country
{
    public int AdProductID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string AdProduct
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Country> list = new List<Country>
    {
        new Country{ AdProduct="Select", AdProductID = -1},
        new Country{ AdProduct="Select1", AdProductID = 1},
        new Country{ AdProduct="Select2", AdProductID = 2},
        new Country{ AdProduct="Select3", AdProductID = 3},
        new Country{ AdProduct="Select4", AdProductID = 4},
    };

    Cboadproducts.DataContext = list;
}
```

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox Height="23"

              x:Name="Cboadproducts"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="168"
              TabIndex="3"
              DisplayMemberPath="AdProduct"
              SelectedValuePath="AdProdctID" />
```

**EDIT II**

To load a different collection:

In code either `Cboadproducts.DataContext = differentList;`

or

instead of using a List use ObservableCollection and remove items from the collection using `Clear()` and add other items using `Add()`

ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged which notifies the control when the collection has changed and then causes the UI to update.

Comment: I tried with datacontext  and the values are getting binded but its not displaying any values...i tried to see the values in the message box in the selection change event..even I'm getting the binded value in the message box but its not displaying in the combo box.

Comment: Did you have a look at the debug output? Any (binding) errors there?

Comment: nope..i dont find any errors in debug..Is there any other method to load combo box..

Comment: I added my test code. can you see any differences from yours?

Comment: thanks its works...I missed the ItemsSource="{Binding}" after adding that its works as charm..

Comment: You're welcome. Were you loading the other combo boxes by adding to the Items property?

Comment: nope..i didnt include that in the other combo boxes..but it was working fine till now...

Comment: i need to reload this combo box whenever value changes in the master combo box. but if i cleared the items using the items.clear() method..its showing error"Operation not supported on read-only collection."..how shall i clear and load the values everytime...

Comment: Do not use `Clear()`. Instead replace the collection that is assigned to the DataContext with the collection that should be displayed.

Comment: any samples pls..right now i'm assigning the new values in the list to the data context but its not getting updated..